# FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: java, android, opencv, nullpointerexception

I am new to Android programming. I need to open the camera with OpenCV library and I have followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z2vrioEr9OI&t=1255s) video tutorial.

However, the app has been stopped on the emulator at runtime and only view a message that says "app_name has stoped try to open again". There are lots of errors, I have fixed many of them but I can't fix the others. This is my logcat:

```
09-02 04:00:52.628 9058-9058/samaa.example.com.opencv249 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: samaa.example.com.opencv249, PID: 9058
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{samaa.example.com.opencv249/samaa.example.com.opencv249.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
   at samaa.example.com.opencv249.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:55)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

And here is my main Acivity:

```
package samaa.example.com.opencv249;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2 {

    private static String TAG="MainActivity";
    JavaCameraView javaCameraView;
    Mat mRgba;
    BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallBack = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status){
                case BaseLoaderCallback.SUCCESS: {
                    javaCameraView.enableView();
                    break;
                }
                default:{
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    };
    static {
        if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "successfull");
        }
        else {
            Log.i(TAG,"failed");
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            javaCameraView = (javaCameraView).findViewById(R.id.java_camera_view);
            javaCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
            javaCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);

    }
    @Override

    protected void  onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        if(javaCameraView != null)
            javaCameraView.disableView();
    }

    @Override

    protected void  onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(javaCameraView != null)
            javaCameraView.disableView();
    }

    @Override
    protected void  onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        javaCameraView.enableView();

       /* if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "successfull");
            mLoaderCallBack.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
        }
        else {
            Log.i(TAG,"failed");
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_2, this, mLoaderCallBack);
        }*/


    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
        mRgba= new Mat(height,width, CvType.CV_8UC4);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStopped() {
        mRgba.release();

    }

    @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        mRgba= inputFrame.rgba();
        return mRgba;
    }

    private void requestRecordAudioPermission() {
        //check API version, do nothing if API version < 23!
        int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentapiVersion > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // Should we show an explanation?
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)) {

                    // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                    // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                    // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

                } else {

                    // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                    Log.d("Activity", "Granted!");

                } else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Log.d("Activity", "Denied!");
                    finish();
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference" more less means NullPointerException. [How to fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to find reference from an un-initialized view with `(javaCameraView).find` where as you need to use the Casting so use

```
javaCameraView = (JavaCameraView)findViewById(R.id.java_camera_view);
//Casting,class name ^^^^^^^^^
//    notice no dot(.)          ^
```

whereas the below statement will try to find a `view` with id `java_camera_view` from `javaCameraView` object which is yet to be initialized

```
 (javaCameraView).findViewById(R.id.java_camera_view);
```

Comment: i did not notice that ^_^ thanx alot.. but it still not working with a new error says :"Error:(55, 31) error: cannot find symbol class javaCameraView"

Comment: on which line   or is it everywhere ?

Comment: it is on everywhere on all "javaCameraView"

Comment: seems like you have issue with import statement `import org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView;` that opencv is not properly configured with your project

Comment: i dont know if there is something wrong with the configuration of opencv but i follow the video tutorial ... i get only one difference that in the tutorial the Libs of opencv cobied in jniLibs folder inside the app directory and i do the same what the youtuber doing but the jniLibs folder, that i create, appear under "cpp"  name -_-